# Dynamic dispalying of data based on fields of a collection

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

So, I have collection of documents with the following fields (id, usera, userb, message). (Document name room) Now I want to name a room based on the user who is logged in. ie if I am user a I want userb to be displayed and vice versa. I have the code below and it seems to be outputting only userb all the time. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<template name="rooms">
<h4>Contacts:</h4>
<ul>
{{#each rooms}}
    {{> room}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

```
<template name="room">
<li style="cursor: pointer; {{roomstyle}}">
    {{#if useraIs}}
    {{userb}}
    {{/if}}
     </li>
```

});

```
 Template.room.helpers({
useraIs: function(usera) {
    return this.usera==Meteor.userId();
  }
```

});

Comment: read more on meteortips.com

Comment: So many incorrect on basic things. And probably duplicate with dozen/hundred stackoverflow meteor question. The best place to start meteor beside meteortips.com is meteor guide.

Comment: If you could comment on the useraIs part of the code, it would be more helpful. I eddied my post to remove all the unnecessary part.